# Move_group_interface_tutorial: orientation vs. position

Tags: ros, moveit, movegroup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I am learning how to plan my robot arm with moveit following pr2_tutorials: http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html

What i dont understand is:

1 - what it's the diference between orientation and position?

2 - I try to move my end effector with only position x,y,z and it didnt work, why?

3 - Right now i always plan with joint space goal and read the positions to then plan with pose goal or path. Is this the way, or it is a better method to plan with coordinates?

Can you help me clarify my doubts?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254650/move_group_interface_tutorial:-orientation-vs.-position/) by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2017-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For 1) I am assuming you are asking about lines such as

> box_pose.orientation.w = 1.0;

For object in 3-dimensional space, it requires 6-degrees of specification to uniquely identify a pose.  Positions x, y, and z as well as orientation such as roll, pitch, and yaw.  There are several ways to specify orientation with some easier for a human to understand/visualize and some "easier" for a computer to use.  In this case quaternions are used which are a desirable representation for a number of reasons.  Quaternions for rotation are represented by four numbers in vector form [x y z w].  The line of code above sets the w component to 1.0 with the rest defaulting to zero.  As a rotation, this is equivalent to identity (no rotation) which in this case specifies orientation the same as the reference frame (frame_id).

For 2) By omitting that line, the quaternion values default to all zero, which is not a valid rotation (must be of unit length) which is probably why you get an error in that case.

You can try something like this [tool](http://quaternions.online/) for visualizing rotation quaternions or if you want to know more try these references:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion

http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/

[https://www.amazon.com/Quaternions-Rotation-Sequences-Applications-Aerospace/dp/0691102988](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691102988)

And finally for 3) usually your task will dictate how you obtain coordinates.  For example, industrial robots poses can be taught with a teach pendant (similar to your current approach) or in other applications where positions are determined online and/or from sensor data the pose is more easily expressed in Cartesian coordinates.  I would suggest using whatever method makes the most sense for the application at hand.  This will become more evident as you learn.

---

Originally posted by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) with karma: 525 on 2017-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) on 2017-02-14**:
Thanks. I'm new to implementing robots so this is a new world for me. I really apreciate for the references you gived, it helped a lot to understand better this part